# How to stop Thread Intercommunication?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

JAVA Thread beginner, I have two threads both are counting from 1 to 20 and One thread is printing even no. Other Thread is printing odd no. one after another Concurrently like odd-1 even-2 odd-3 even-4... odd-17 even -18 odd-19 using Thread Inter communication(using wait and notify method on some same instance) .

this part is executing fine. but in the END of counting Either of thread is going in wait state and other thread is getting terminated.

So How to get rid of this problem? What is the best approach should I use to get out of this problem?

Code :

```
public class OddEvenNumbers {

    static A a= new A();
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        OddNumbers odd = new OddNumbers();
        EvenNumbers even = new EvenNumbers();

        Thread th1 = new Thread(odd);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(even);
        th1.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        th2.start();
    }
}

public class EvenNumbers implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i=1;i<20;i++)
        {
            synchronized (OddEvenNumbers.a) {
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Even Numbers : "+i);

                }
                try {

                    OddEvenNumbers.a.notify();
                    OddEvenNumbers.a.wait();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }

}



public class OddNumbers implements Runnable {


    public void run() {

        System.out.println("In ODD run Method"); 


        for(int i=1;i<20;i++)
        {
            synchronized (OddEvenNumbers.a) {

                if(i%2!=0)
                {
                    System.out.println("ODD Number "+i);

                }
                try {

                    OddEvenNumbers.a.wait();
                    OddEvenNumbers.a.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: If always one of the 2 threads is waiting for the other it doesn't make sense to use different threads. You're just wasting a lot of time on synchronisation. Maybe using a [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) could help in case you have a problem that indeed allows parallel processing.

Comment: @fabian, this is a very common homework exercise.  You're right, it would be a stupid thing to do in a real program, but it teaches them basics of synchronizing threads.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But it is a simple Example I am doing to understand the wait and notify concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last wait() call (when the counter equals 20), this way the last printing thread will not wait without a chance of getting a notify().

Comment: It helped me to resole the problem. but is it right approach to handle wait and Notify or we need to some other approach or predefined classes

Comment: I think that for this simple task this is the appropriate simple method to use - there are some other tools (semaphores, for example), but they might be a bit too much for this.